# Set function data into variable using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to set the width of an external image (from another url) into a variable, so I can use the newly assigned variable on another function.

The problem is that I get `undefined` message on the variable, see the code below.

```
var site_url = 'http://fabricjs.com/assets/1.svg';

function getMeta(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() { callback(this.width, this.height); }
}
var a = getMeta(site_url, function(width, height) { 
    return width; 
});

alert(a); //undefined
```

What am I doing wrong, how should I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with asynchronous functions, you need to put the rest of the code in the callback function (or use promises). Here, you need to put `alert` inside callback.

```
var a = getMeta(site_url, function(width, height) { 
  alert(width);
});
```

Comment: I don't want to alert it, I want to use the variable 'a' which should be an integer with the width number.

Comment: Ok, but I've already said that you **must put the rest of the code** where you use `a` in the callback function.

Comment: when I print 'a' it's still undefined, is there a way so this variable is just a number ? why can't I return width; ? Can you show me an example ?

Comment: Nevermind, the duplicate says it's impossible

Comment: @Lindow. No, you didn't understand it. It is not impossible. You must write `a = width` at the start of the callback function and everything after it you must put inside callback. **You cannot return anything from asynchronous function** becauae it is called **after** you print `a`, understood?

Comment: I'm really visual and take time to understand when it's written, sorry to bother... But I think I get what you mean, I can only call width, height inside the getMeta function but I cannot assign it the integers to "a" as it was a number.

Comment: @Lindow. Correct.